# JNDI lookup by class

Tags: java, jndi

We have a bunch of services (EJBs) that we want to lookup using the local or remote interfaces. It doesn't matter if we would potentially find more than one implementation since if we let that happen that's on purpose.

Since we don't have direct access to an EJB container, we need to use JNDI lookups.

Currently, we're iterating over the contexts using `Context#listBindings("")` and check whether the returned object in each binding is either a context - in which case we call the lookup recursively - or could be assigned to the interface we're looking for - in that case we're done.

However, doing that might result in a whole bunch of lookups, since I'd have to call `list("")` for every subcontext I find (which might be quite a lot in bigger applications).

So is there a way to do class based lookups in JNDI in one call (or a defined number of calls)?

Btw, we're doing this on JBoss 4.2.3.GA so we don't have access to Java EE 6 JNDI implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one word: No. Your use case is too special.

But you have some options:

1. Why don't you register a Spring `ApplicationContext` via JNDI? That would allow you to call `getBean(type)`.
2. Instead of doing those lookups again and again, add a factory to your code which caches the lookups?
3. How about creating a "Service Lookup EJB"?

Comment: I'm currently caching the names, then try look those up and if that fails I purge that name from the cache and search again, so that would be option 2. I also used option 3 for a while, looking up a bean that retrieves its container and searches it for the required service, but aquiring that container is JBoss specific (might even depend on the version) so I'd rather like to avoid that. I'll think about option 1, thanks for that hint.